# Why is this LINQ query throwing an InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, generic-list

I am getting an InvalidCastException on this line:

```
List<Student> studentsWithSameSurname =
    (List<Student>)_studentsList
        .Where(i => i.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text.Trim())
        .GroupBy(j => j.FamilyID);
```

`_studentsList` is a `List<Student>`, so I don't know why (`List<Student>`) is an invalid cast.

For those who want more context, this is a Winforms app wherein I serialize a generic list of a custom class to a json file, and then deserialize it when I want to work with the data, and use LINQ to query it.

`_studentsList` is defined this way:

```
List<Student> _studentsList;
```

The Student class is:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int FamilyID { get; set; }
    public bool EnrolledInAYttFM { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnrolledOrHiatusAYttFM { get; set; }
    public bool GivesBibleReading { get; set; }
    public bool PresentsICRVBS { get; set; }
    public bool IsHouseholder { get; set; }
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddr { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekOfLastAssignment { get; set; }
    public int RecommendedNextTalkTypeID { get; set; }
    public int NextCounselPoint { get; set; }
}
```

The logic behind what I'm trying to do is:

If a Student is added, and their surname already exists in the generic list, it needs to be determined if the second instance of that name is a member of the same household as the previous one. More specifically, if a "Smith" is added, and they are the first person with that surname, they get the next available familyID; otherwise (if that surname has already been entered) it must be determined if they belong to one of the households already entered, or if they are the first member of a new household:

```
Student surNameCandidateRecord = _studentsList.SingleOrDefault(s => s.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text);
if (null == surNameCandidateRecord)
{
    student.FamilyID = _studentsList.Max(x => x.FamilyID) + 1;
}
else // at least one family with that surname exists already
{
    student.FamilyID = GetFamilyID();
}
```

The GetFamilyID() method is the one that is throwing this exception, and here it is in its entirety:

```
private int GetFamilyID()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> familyIDsAndNames;

    // InvalidCastException on the line below
    List<Student> studentsWithSameSurname = (List<Student>)_studentsList.Where(i => i.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text.Trim()).GroupBy(j => j.FamilyID);
    // </ InvalidCastException on the line above

    familyIDsAndNames = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    foreach (Student s in studentsWithSameSurname)
    {
        string fullNameWithFamilyIdPrepended = String.Format("({0}). {1} {2}", s.FamilyID, s.FirstName, s.LastName);
        familyIDsAndNames.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.FamilyID, fullNameWithFamilyIdPrepended));
    }
    ChooseFamilyForm cff = new ChooseFamilyForm(familyIDsAndNames);
    cff.ShowDialog();
    return AYttFMConstsAndUtils.familyIDSelected;
}
```

At the point whe[n,re] the InvalidCastException is thrown, the contents of the generic list is (the names and email addresses have been changed to protect the spamshy):

```
[{"StudentID":1,"FamilyID":1,"EnrolledInAYttFM":true,"DateEnrolledOrHiatusAYttFM":"2016-02-12T21:52:55.9560088-08:00","GivesBibleReading":false,"PresentsICRVBS":true,"IsHouseholder":true,"IsMale":false,"FirstName":"Carly","LastName":"Shannon","EmailAddr":"carlyjeannette@att.net","WeekOfLastAssignment":"2015-08-12T21:52:50.6959113-07:00","RecommendedNextTalkTypeID":3,"NextCounselPoint":16},{"StudentID":2,"FamilyID":2,"EnrolledInAYttFM":true,"DateEnrolledOrHiatusAYttFM":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","GivesBibleReading":false,"PresentsICRVBS":true,"IsHouseholder":true,"IsMale":false,"FirstName":"Jennifer","LastName":"Volando","EmailAddr":"jenni_v@ymail.com","WeekOfLastAssignment":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","RecommendedNextTalkTypeID":0,"NextCounselPoint":0}]
```

...and I am trying to add a second person with the surname "Volando" (hence the routing of the code to the GetFamilyID() method).

My LINQ query is probably wrong, but I don't know in which way.

### UPDATE

This is what I successfully used, based on Tordek's answer:

```
List<Student> studentsWithSameSurname = (List<Student>)_studentsList
        .Where(i => i.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text.Trim())
        .OrderBy(j => j.FamilyID)
        .ToList();
```

I will award a bounty to dicho answer ASAP; since reaching 10K, I'm going to do a Carnegie and "give away" all points over that.

Comment: Because that's not a list of `Student` objects...

Comment: You cannot cast Group By to the original List, because group by returns the count of students per family. Here, you will have two columns (Count and FamilyId). If you want to know the count of each family there is no reason to cast this to List of Students.

Comment: Your `GroupBy` seems unnecessary; why are you trying to group the results by `FamilyId`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this line

```
List<Student> studentsWithSameSurname =
    (List<Student>)_studentsList
        .Where(i => i.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text.Trim())
        .GroupBy(j => j.FamilyID);
```

You're not casting `_studentsList`; you're casting the whole expression. In other words, that is equivalent to

```
    (List<Student>)(_studentsList
        .Where(i => i.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text.Trim())
        .GroupBy(j => j.FamilyID));
```

and not (as you expect)

```
    ((List<Student>)_studentsList)
        .Where(i => i.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text.Trim())
        .GroupBy(j => j.FamilyID);
```

If you want to obtain a list as a result of your Linq query, you must use the .ToList() method:

```
     studentsList
        .Where(i => i.LastName == textBoxLastName.Text.Trim())
        .GroupBy(j => j.FamilyID)
        .ToList();
```

However, your result is not a `List<Student>` but a new type, because the `GroupBy` method creates a new list-of-lists-of-students type. The result of a `GroupBy` expression os of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, U>>` where T is your grouping variable and U is the elements' type; in your case, it will be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Student>>`, if `FamilyID` is of type `int`.

Comment: There's a `GroupBy()` call there... it's a collection of groupings. Some decision has to be made on what student is to be in that list.

Comment: @JeffMercado I've added a clarification on the end.

Comment: I will bountify this ASAP, to reward this answer. Please see my update.